# Opencv Rect only creating one rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, particle-filter

In my attempt to implement particle filter, I have first manually drawn a rectangle(x,y,w,h) around the car in my image (in red color), then i took 50 particles, and assigned them noise i.e x=x+noise(0,15) and y=y+noise(0,15).

Then i wanted to dram all the rectangles for each particle in green color, but instead of showing 50 rectangles, it is only showing one rectangle.

```
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



const int N = 50;// no of particles

string intToString(int number){

    //this function has a number input and string output
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}



int main()
{


    Mat frame;
    frame = imread("f (1).png");
    namedWindow("Out");


    //locating the car manually
    Rect car(175, 210, 42, 31);


    //making a rectangle around the car
    rectangle(frame, car, Scalar(0, 0,255), 1, 8, 0);



    //getting tht height and width of the frame
    const int FRAME_HEIGHT = frame.rows;
    const int FRAME_WIDTH = frame.cols;


    //Particle filter initialization

    Mat Init = (Mat_<float>(4, 1) << car.x, car.y, 0, 0);


    //for a gaussian noise distribution
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0, 15);


    //Initializing the particles
    std::vector<cv::Mat> particle(N, cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_32F));


    cout << car.x << " " << car.y << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        particle[i].at<float>(0, 0) = Init.at<float>(0, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(1, 0) = Init.at<float>(1, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(2, 0) = 0.0;
        particle[i].at<float>(3, 0) = 0.0;
        cout << particle[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x = particle[i].at<float>(0, 0);
        int y = particle[i].at<float>(1, 0);

        rectangle(frame, Rect(x, y, 42, 31), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }

    imshow("Out", frame);


    waitKey();





    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this

[image]

The particle x y coordinates are in the following image, The first entry is of the the car that was manually hard coded, rest all are the particle coordinates.

[image]

Comment: What are the positions of perticles just before drawing? It seems all particles are having almost the same positions...

Comment: Well, separate your problem into multiple tasks and evaluate each one and first of all: is your random number generator `distribution(generator)` working? E.g. replace it with `rand()%15`.

Comment: @marol I have edited the question, The image contains the particle x and y values, and they are quite different only

Comment: @William Its working, I have updated that the particles x & y values

Comment: great answer by @marol. Try simpler containers like std::vector<cv::Rect> or std::vector<cv::Point>.

Comment: locating the problem could have been simplified by printing the particle positions again right before drawing.

Comment: @Micka that's exactly what I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem might be in vector initialization. In the line:

```
 //Initializing the particles
    std::vector<cv::Mat> particle(N, cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_32F));
```

What you do is to create N Mat objects initialized to size 4 by 1 of type float. So this seems to be okay...Wait! **What if all Mat objects in the vector share the same matrix data?** We all know that Mat container has a header and data. Data is not copied when the headers are assigned to each other or copy constructor is executed. Like in our case. What exactly Let's imagine how the vector constructor might work:

```
template<class T>
vector::vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) {
    // how it can be written? Probably in the following way:
    this->resize(n); // allocates using allocator
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         this->innerBuffer[i] = alloc(val); // runs copy constructor with argument val
                    // in our case, this is cv::Mat(const cv::Mat &)
}
```

And if you think about copying of cv::Mat container,  **only header is copied**. If you would like to clone the data itself, you have to specify it directly, e.g. using Mat::clone() method. And vector constructor definitely does not use clone(). So the data is not cloned and all Mat objects share the same data, although headers are different!

You can easy check if this is true (I would be surprised if it wasn't): Change the fragment of code from:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        particle[i].at<float>(0, 0) = Init.at<float>(0, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(1, 0) = Init.at<float>(1, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(2, 0) = 0.0;
        particle[i].at<float>(3, 0) = 0.0;
        cout << particle[i] << "\n"; // it is obvius that HERE particles are different
                 // beacuse in the next loop run you overwrite them!
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x = particle[i].at<float>(0, 0);
        int y = particle[i].at<float>(1, 0);

        rectangle(frame, Rect(x, y, 42, 31), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        particle[i].at<float>(0, 0) = Init.at<float>(0, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(1, 0) = Init.at<float>(1, 0) + distribution(generator);
        particle[i].at<float>(2, 0) = 0.0;
        particle[i].at<float>(3, 0) = 0.0;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << particle[i] << "\n";

        int x = particle[i].at<float>(0, 0);
        int y = particle[i].at<float>(1, 0);

        rectangle(frame, Rect(x, y, 42, 31), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
```

I expect that all particles are the same.

**Reference:** ([here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__vector_8h-source.html#l00198))

```
 vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __value,
00199          const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
00200       : _Base(__n, __a)
00201       { this->_M_impl._M_finish = std::uninitialized_fill_n(this->
00202                                 _M_impl._M_start,
00203                                 __n, __value); }
00204
```