# std::vector does not create new reference of cv::Mat for more than one vector entries - data gets overriden when initializing the matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector

So here is something that I came upon that really bothered me and made me try and figure out why does it work this way:

If have the following super simplistic, error prone code just to show an example:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newData(3,cv::Mat(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type));

int counter = 0;
for(int b=0; b<3; b++){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            newData[b].at<int>(i,j) = counter++;
            std::cout << newData[b].at<T>(i,j) << std::endl;
        }       
    }
}

for(int b=0; b<3; b++){
    std::cout << newData[b] << std::endl;
}
```

Printout:

```
[18, 19, 20;
  21, 22, 23;
  24, 25, 26]
[18, 19, 20;
  21, 22, 23;
  24, 25, 26]
[18, 19, 20;
  21, 22, 23;
  24, 25, 26]
```

**Why is the same reference being used for the different vector entries?**
I am forced to create the different matrices separately as opposed to creating them along with the vector itself.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: btw, should be  `newData[b].at<T>()`

Comment: Those are the "awesome" semantics of `cv::Mat` copy. It is essentially a shared pointer. You need to explicitly copy things. IIRC there is a `cv::Mat::clone()` method for that.

Comment: ^^ oh yes. this will make a vector with 3 Mats, but they all point to the *same* pixel data !

Comment: @berak, thanks! I fixed the typo. juanchopanza, yeah I wondered if something like this was happening. But the cv::Mat::clone() requires an already existing Mat object. What would be the proper way of initializing the vector of x number of cv::Mats? Do I have to stick to the manual creation of cv::Mat?

Comment: please refer to my answer, it describes exactly what you are asking : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257784/opencv-rect-only-creating-one-rectangle/24259415#24259415 This basically what @juanchopanza said and it goes more in detail in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `cv::Mat` has reference semantics, so copying `cv::Mat` objects results in the copies sharing the data with the original. Thus initializing a vector in this way

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newData(N, a_cv_mat);
```

will result in the vector containing N `cv::Mat`s all sharing the same data as `a_cv_mat`.

To avoid having `cv::Mat` objects that refer to the same data, you can initialize the vector using a brace enclosed initializaiton list:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newData{cv::Mat(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type),
                             cv::Mat(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type),
                             cv::Mat(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type)};
```

If you do not know the number of elements at compile time, you can emplace them into the vector one by one:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newData
newData.emplace_back(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type);
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can push each matrix into the vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newData
newData.push_back(cv::Mat(height, width, cv::DataType<T>::type));
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I am already using the push_back method to manually initialize the vector with new matrices, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it. Also, the brace enclosed initialization list won't really work for me since the number of matrices is determined at runtime...I guess I will have to stick to the manual initialization using a loop.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov If you have C++11, you could also consider using `emplace_back` to save some copying (although the amount of data being copied is minimal, which is presumably the motivation for giving `cv::Mat` such counter-intuitive semantics.)

Comment: awesome suggestion and a very useful method call. Thanks! I hope this post helps another soul from a couple of hours of headache wondering what's going on ;)